# Play 2 start up method failed to execute Java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, startup

I have some code in the Play 2.5 application that executes on start up. It works well on my local machine but fails to execute on production server. 
Here is relevant code:

This is Constructor of start up class:

```
@Inject
public StartupController(ActorSystem system, CreditCardChargeJob chargeJob, 
        ProductService productService, RoleService roleService) {

    Logger.info("Application startup...");

    this.system = system;
    this.chargeJob = chargeJob;
    this.productService = productService;
    this.roleService = roleService;

    fillDatabase();

    createCreditCardChargeJob();

}
```

Here is module that defines the binding:

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {

   @Override
   protected void configure() {

       Logger.info("Binding on startup class...");

       bind(StartupController.class).asEagerSingleton();

   }

}
```

And my application.conf section where I define modules:

```
play.modules {
   enabled += be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule
   enabled += modules.CustomDeadboltHook
   enabled += modules.Module
}
```

The logs output on localhost is:

```
 [info] application - Binding on startup class...
 [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
 [info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at    jdbc:mysql://localhost/creditperfection
 [info] application - Application startup...
 [info] application - ActorSystem: akka://application
 [info] application - Credit card charging job is running...
```

And on the server there is only this:

```
 [INFO] from play.api.db.DefaultDBApi in main - Database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/creditperfection
 [INFO] from play.api.Play in main - Application started (Prod)
```

So, as you can see from the logs controller that should have been executed on start up failed to run for some reason.
It seems like the problem is not in code as it works on localhost and I really stuck with it. If anyone has at least slightest idea what can cause such behavior please let me know your ideas.

Appreciate the help!
Vitalii

Comment: do you have different configs for db on prod?